# onMouseEnter not firing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

I'm running the latest version of Firefox Quantum (58.0.2). The `onMouseEnter` event is being fired in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

```
handleMouseEnter = () => {
    console.log('mouse enter') // not logging in Firefox, logged in other browsers
}

handleMouseLeave = () => {
    console.log('mouse leave')
}

render () {
    return (
        <div
            onMouseEnter={this.handleMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={this.handleMouseLeave}
        >
            <p>Hover me</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Are there possible compatibility issues with the latest version of Firefox that I'm running?

Comment: Works fine for me on Firefox 58.0.2: https://codesandbox.io/s/3ym1wry8v6

Answer (score 0):

Mhm look like full support in all browsers but have a look at the example code below! **Is it working?** `:)`

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5B3.png)

```js
function mouseEnter() {
  console.log("entered!!!")
}
```

```html
<div onmouseenter="mouseEnter()">
  <p>Enter with mouse pointer</p>
</div>
```